# Handle in Python date in format EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy

Tags: python, string, date

In a dataset, I have some date-time in the format EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy, like this "Mon May 18 20:25:32 GMT+02:00 2020".
How can I convert in Python this string in ISO format and in the machine local time?

Comment: Dates have no format. They are binary values. Formats apply only when parsing a date literal (a string) into an actual date, or formatting a date as text for display or writing it to a file

Comment: So either the dataset contains the wrong type, string instead of date, or you're trying to fix something that's not broken. If the dataset contains strings, you need to fix the code that loads it and ensure the correct type is used.

Answer (score 1):

First install `dateutil` through `python -m pip install python-dateutil`.

Then use next code:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow66777922#main.py)

```
import datetime, dateutil.parser
s = 'Mon May 18 20:25:32 GMT+02:00 2020'
t = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z%z %Y') # 'EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy'
print(t.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzutc()))   # UTC TimeZone
print(t.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzlocal())) # Local TimeZone
```

Output:

```
2020-05-18 18:25:32+00:00
2020-05-18 21:25:32+03:00
```

---

Also one easy way is to use dateutil's parser to auto-guess format, but it may work incorrectly sometimes:

[Try it online!](https://replit.com/@moytrage/StackOverflow66777922var2#main.py)

```
import dateutil.parser
s = 'Mon May 18 20:25:32 GMT+02:00 2020'
t = dateutil.parser.parse(s)
print(t.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzutc()))   # UTC TimeZone
print(t.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzlocal())) # Local TimeZone
```

Output (which has guessed timezone incorrectly):

```
2020-05-18 22:25:32+00:00
2020-05-19 01:25:32+03:00
```

One way to make dateutil's guesser work correctly is to remove `' GMT'` substring, if you have same substring for timezone name everywhere. Code below:

```
import dateutil.parser
s = 'Mon May 18 20:25:32 GMT+02:00 2020'.replace(' GMT', '')
t = dateutil.parser.parse(s)
print(t.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzutc()))   # UTC TimeZone
print(t.astimezone(dateutil.tz.tzlocal())) # Local TimeZone
```

Output:

```
2020-05-18 18:25:32+00:00
2020-05-18 21:25:32+03:00
```